# Match the multiple values and replace the repeated values with one value

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, match

I have one string like below.Match the Alphabets within the string.The result is `x,x,x,y,y,y` .The x,y repeat three time.My question is how replace repeated same value with one value.i need ah answer like `x,y` .

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "-10x+10x-10x-10y+6y-8y";
    var result = str.match(/[a-z]/g);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [negative look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "-10x+10x-10x-10y+6y-8y";
    var result = str.match(/([a-z])(?!.*\1)/g);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/dX4nB3/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thank you @pranav c balan.can you explain the regex?

Comment: @PranavCBalan will this give the same intended result if x and y are not always together?

Comment: @PranavCBalan great, tested the same too +1

Answer (score 1):

To get the unique variable names, you can add this line after your regex

```
var map = {}; 
result.forEach( function(val){ map[val] = true } );
result = Object.keys(map)
```

**DEMO**

```js
    var str = "-10x+10x-10x-10y+6y-8y";
    var result = str.match(/[a-z]/g);
    var map = {}; 
    result.forEach( function(val){ map[val] = true } );
    result = Object.keys(map);
    document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4)
```